# Почему не срабатывает мой js при добавлении маски imask

Tags: javascript

У меня стоит прослушиватель событий на input, я добавляю маску и прослушиватель перестает работать.
Я только новичок в js, помогите, пожалуйста

```js
<script src="https://unpkg.com/imask"></script>

<script>
            
let input = document.querySelector('.input');
let inputList = document.querySelectorAll('.input__item');

var maskOptions = {
   mask: '00-00',
   lazy: false
} 

var mask = new IMask(input, maskOptions);

input.addEventListener("input", function () {
  inputList.forEach((input) => input.classList.remove('hidden'))
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" class="input">
  <input type="text" class="input__item hidden">
  <input type="text" class="input__item hidden">
  <input type="text" class="input__item hidden">
  <input type="text" class="input__item hidden">
  <input type="text" class="input__item hidden">
  <input type="text" class="input__item hidden">
  <input type="text" class="input__item hidden">
  <input type="text" class="input__item hidden">
</div>
```

Comment: переменные c дефисом нельзя

Comment: Извините, опечатался. В проектном коде (он больше) и значения другие. Листенер срабатывал до маски и после того, как я ее убираю

Answer (score 0):

Нет, уважаемый, маска тут не причём. Дело в том, что переменные называть надо **корректно**. Дефисов в именах переменных быть не должно.

Как правило в *Javascript* имена переменных пишутся в *camelCase*

Comment: Извините, опечатался. 
В проектном коде (он больше) и значения другие. Листенер срабатывал до маски и после того, как я ее убираю